# Looks like the wrong package is available on the spark downloads page. The name reads pre built for hadoop3.3 but the tgz file is marked as hadoop3.2

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

[image]

Does the tgz have Hadoop 3.3 but it was written wrong or it is 3.2 Hadoop version only?

Comment: This should be reported to Spark mailing list or JIRA rather than Stackoverflow

Comment: Raised that in their Jira Support https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38218

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the tgz and check the version inside `jars/`. It contains `haddoop-client-{version}.jar`

Comment: I could see the Hadoop client version 3.3.1 in the jars when i extracted tgz.